# Adding two Soap header tags

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui, soapheader

I'm trying to invoke a SOAP 1.2 WS which need a SOAP Header.

I'm using an integration designer called SAP Hana Cloud Integration, I'm receiving a full XML message but without a header and the receiver system must receive the MessageId to accept the data. The script is full, I took the one from the [online documentation](https://proddps.hana.ondemand.com/dps/d/preview/93810d568bee49c6b3d7b5065a30b0ff/2015.10/en-US/frameset.html?8a2827d030b345f998199774266b9810.html) and I'v adapted to my need :

I managed to make it work using SOAP UI after Enabling WS-A addressing and make it generate a random UUID
[image]

In the SOAP UI log I found out that the message header sent to the receiver was the following :

```
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <wsa:MessageID>uuid:8122ffc1-62ee-436c-a284-224e49988013</wsa:MessageID>
   <wsa:Action>http://sap.com/xi/AP/HumanCapitalManagementMasterDataReplication/Global/HumanCapitalManagementMasterDataReplicationEmployeeMasterDataReplicationIn/ReplicateCompleteEmployeeMasterDataRequest</wsa:Action>
</soap:Header>
```

I tried to create the same header using Groovy :

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader;
import org.apache.cxf.headers.Header;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import com.sap.it.api.ITApiFactory;
import com.sap.it.api.securestore.SecureStoreService;
import com.sap.it.api.securestore.UserCredential;


def Message processData(Message message) {
String uuid = "uuid:" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

String ActionUrl ="http://sap.com/xi/AP/HumanCapitalManagementMasterDataReplication/Global/HumanCapitalManagementMasterDataReplicationEmployeeMasterDataReplicationIn/ReplicateCompleteEmployeeMasterDataRequest";

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();

//WSA MessageID
Element MessageId = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "wsa:MessageID");  
MessageId.setTextContent(uuid);
doc.appendChild(MessageId);

//WSA Action
Element Action = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "wsa:Action");  
Action.setTextContent(ActionUrl);
doc.appendChild(Action);

SoapHeader header = new SoapHeader(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", MessageId.getLocalName()), MessageId);         
header.setMustUnderstand(true);
List  headersList  = new ArrayList<SoapHeader>();
headersList.add(header);

SoapHeader header2 = new SoapHeader(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", Action.getLocalName()), Action);         
headersList.add(header2);
header2.setMustUnderstand(true);
message.setHeader("org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list", headersList);

return message;
}
```

But it turned that it's impossible to set two root nodes under the header, here is the error message :
cause: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.

Any idea on how to achieve this ? Thanks !
BR,
Amine.

Comment: what is your test case structure? When soapui can take care of those, why doing it with groovy?  Can you check the raw request of the same if it has duplicate data? by the way, the above script does not seem to be full, just part of it? Finally are you sending the request using groovy or request test step?

Comment: I'm using an integration designer called SAP Hana Cloud Integration, I'm receiving a full XML message but without a header and the receiver system must receive the MessageId to accept the data.

The script is full, I took the one from the online documentation and I'v adapted to my need : [link](https://proddps.hana.ondemand.com/dps/d/preview/93810d568bee49c6b3d7b5065a30b0ff/2015.10/en-US/frameset.html?999aa87a429846a4a3f3f8d5818dd0d5.html)

Comment: Can you please go thru the previous comments/questions and update?

Comment: Is groovy script objective is to just create the request?

Comment: Yes just to modify the header.

Comment: Can you show how you get the request into the groovy script? Does it have empty `Header` element?

Answer (score 0):

Via groovy script in HCI:

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
def Message processData(Message message) {

       //Headers 
       def map = message.getHeaders();
       def value = map.get("oldHeader");
       message.setHeader("oldHeader", value + "modified");
       message.setHeader("newHeader", "yourValue");

       return message;
}
```

In designer web application (not ECLIPSE) much simpler:

Content Modifier 
-> Message Header before sending request -> YourHeader | Constant | java.lang.String | YourValue ...